# If/else Statement with macOS terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-sierra

So I'm quite new to the macOS terminal and I would like to execute a simple command in which if the hidden mac folders are shown, hide them and if they are hidden, show them.

I'm mainly used to python so my first reflex would be:

```
if defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles is NO: 
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES 
else: 
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
```

Now I'm pretty sure that this wouldn't work but how could I achieve something like this inside a shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ '1' = $(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles) ]; then
    echo "AppleShowAllFiles is enabled"
elif [ '0' = $(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles) ];   then
    echo "AppleShowAllFiles is not enabled"
else
    echo "defaults returned some other value"
fi
```

Or this to assign the return value of defaults to a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

defaultsReturn=$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)

if [ '1' = "$defaultsReturn" ]; then
    echo "AppleShowAllFiles is enabled"
elif [ '0' = "$defaultsReturn" ]; then
    echo "AppleShowAllFiles is not enabled"
else
    echo "defaults returned some other value: $defaultsReturn"
fi
```

Comment: I think I voted took quickly. The above answer is right

Answer (score 3):

To type if then else on terminal

```
if (( 1 == 1));then echo "hi"; fi;
```